# UIDatePicker non-continuous minutes

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uidatepicker

I set my UIDatepicker timeInterval to 30 mins, so it shows it as 30,60 (repeating). I really don't want it to repeat, just show 2 options (like AM/PM). Is there a way to do this without creating it from scratch?

Thanks!

Comment: same issue here.. no one has answer?

Comment: I couldn't get it to do it. I just didn't rewrite it since it would take too much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use UIPicker instead?

```
    UIPickerView *pick=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, datep.frame.origin.y, datep.frame.size.width, datep.frame.size.height)];
[pick setDelegate:self];
[pick setDataSource:self];
[pick setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
[self.view addSubview:pick];

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
return 3;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
if(component==0){
    return 12;
}else{
    return 2;
}

return 2;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
if(component==1){
    if(row==1)
        return @"30";
    else
        return @"00";
    }
else if(component==0){
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row+1];
}else{
    if(row==1)
        return @"AM";
    else
        return @"PM";
    }    
}

-(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return 50;
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return 50;
}
```